# Empty space when reading a file java

Tags: java, file

```
private Scanner inputFile;
private String corpusFileString = "";
try
{
    File file = new File(sourceFile.getText());
    inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file was found.");
    if (text != null)
    {
        translate.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file was not found.");
}

try
{
    numberWords = inputFile.nextInt();
}
catch (InputMismatchException ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The first line on the file must be an integer");
}

while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    corpusFileString = corpusFileString + inputFile.nextLine() + " ";
}
```

So when I read this file, the first line should be an integer(a different variable will hold that) or it will throw an exception.
The rest of the file should be data(another variable for all the data) but for some reason the String contains an empty space at the beginning and when I split it I have to use +1 in my array cause of that empty space.

Comment: This looks more like Java than C#.

Comment: This seems not to be the relevant code part. Show us the code of the `Scanner` class.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Scanner is a built in Java class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that it's reading the first int, then the rest of the first line.

Basically:

15\n a line here \n another line here

Where \n is a newline.

It reads 15, then it reads to \n, which is "" (omitting the newline character). The rest it reads as you expected.

Try using:

```
numberWords = Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine());
```

Instead of

```
numberWords = inputFile.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Trim() to remove whitespace at the beginning and end of the string.
Link to the method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The question was Java, not C#. The issue has to do with the file handling, I think.

Comment: Now that he have changed the labels ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about java. Possibly you have to call `hasNext()` before you try to read with `nextInt()`. This is how .NET readers and enumerators work. In c# I would write something like

```
while (reader.MoveNext()) {
    string s = reader.Current;
}
```

In your case you could try

```
if (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    numberWords = inputFile.nextInt();
}
```